# Modify existing excel file with Python - using filter to sort

Tags: python, excel, sorting, filter

Is there a way to modify an existing excel file by using a filter to sort the data?

The filter is already applied to the relevant columns.
Cells `A2`, `B2` and `C2` already have this little arrow that signifies an applied filter.
I now want to use the "Sort Z to A" option on the data under `B2`.

I've seen the idea to use `pandas`, however I believe that would require recreating all the formatting etc. of the existing excel file.

Maybe there is a simpler solution that can use the existing filters?

Answer (score 0):

The filter for an example would be something like this:

```
colmode = df['column1'].mode()[0]
```

Which gives you the mode of the column.

Then you can create 2 new filters that separates the values before the mode (normally sorted)

```
beforepoint = df['column1'][df['column1']<colmode]
```

and the values after the mode (reversely sorted)

```
afterpoint = df['column1'][df['column1']>colmode]
afterpoint.sort_values(ascending = False)
```

Modifying column1:

```
df['column1'] = beforepoint
df['column1'].append(afterpoint)
df.update(df['column1'])
```